# Array type using Array<T> is forbidden

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

My Ttslint throws a warning with this construction (*Array type using Array is forbidden. Use T[] instead (array-type)* ):

```
Array<string | null> | null
```

Is this correct replacement to the previous one?

```
(string | null)[] | null
```

Comment: Yes, but you can ignore warnings if you want to :)

Comment: Thanks!
But in the variant, where it will be like that:
`string[] | null[] | null` it will be like: array or strings only, or array of null only, or null (no array).
Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are :).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, that is the behavior that the [array-type](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/array-type/) rule enforces, when it is set to `"array"`:

> One of the following arguments must be provided:
>   * `"array"` enforces use of `T[]` for all types `T`.
>   * `"generic"` enforces use of Array for all types `T`.
>   * `"array-simple"` enforces use of `T[]` if `T` is a simple type (primitive or type reference).

You can disable the rule for the entire file by creating a `tslint.json` file in the same folder as the file (or in a parent folder of the file) and writing the following inside it:

```
"rules": {
    "array-type": false
}
```

If you want to choose one of the other settings:

```
"rules": {
    "array-type": [true, "generic"]
}
```

And, as you've mentioned in your question, the equivalent for:

```
Array<string | null> | null
```

is:

```
(string | null)[] | null
```

Answer (score 10):

Accepted answer is correct in case you are using (now deprecated) [tslint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/array-type/), if you are using [typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/array-type.md) rule must be written as:

```js
 "@typescript-eslint/array-type": ["error", { "default": "generic" }],
```

Comment: If you're wondering what the correct answer is in 2023+, it's this one.

You can also use [`"@typescript-eslint/ban-types"`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/ban-types/) for extensive type banning